# Sobolev embedding on $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I came across with the sobolev embedding $H_0^1(\Omega)\stackrel{c}{\hookrightarrow} L^2(\Omega)\hookrightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an open bounded set in $\mathbb{R^n}$. My doubt is whether the embedding $H^1(\Omega) \stackrel{c}{\hookrightarrow} L^2(\Omega) \hookrightarrow (H^1(\Omega))^*$, where * represents the dual of the corresponding space is true?

In Evans book the embedding $H^1(\Omega) \stackrel{c}{\hookrightarrow} L^2(\Omega)$ was given. But what about the other embedding?

Answer (score 0):

The embedding $E$ of $L^2(\Omega)$ into $H^{-1} = (H^1_0(\Omega))^*$ or $(H^1(\Omega))^*$ is given by
$$
(Eu)(v):=\int_\Omega u \ v \ dx.
$$
It is easy to see that this is continuous.